# How to avoid JS USELESS_ARROW_FUNC_BIND error in Storybook Template

Tags: javascript, static-analysis, storybook

Here is the [sample code](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/args) for a story in Storybook 6.0:

```
const Template = (args) => <Button {...args} />;

// Each story then reuses that template
export const Primary = Template.bind({});
```

But, `Template.bind` fails the `USELESS_ARROW_FUNC_BIND` test in DeepScan static analysis:
[image: DeepScan error]

Is there a way of avoiding this linter issue?  I tried `Template({})` but the compiler failed that, indicating the `context` parameter was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const Template = (args) => <Button {...args} />;` line shows that the `Template` doesn't make use of `this`.

However, there is a `Template.bind({})` that assigns `this` to `{}` during the execution of the `WithMarker` function.

As `this` is not being used, you could replace `export const WithMarker = Template.bind({})` with `export const WithMarker = Template`.

Comment: Found code sample that omitted `bind()` element. Tried it and it worked.  Was coming back here to answer my question, though without the level of understanding you provided.  You answer is better than mine would have been :-)  Thanks.